# Ruby omniauth-oauth2 - A Errno::ENETUNREACH -Network is unreachable - connect(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

My Rails application sometimes (from about 2 weeks) crashes during the callback method when an user tries to login with facebook.

This happens randomly and I can't find out a way to solve this problem.

Below the error and a piece of stacktrace:

A Errno::ENETUNREACH occurred in #:
Network is unreachable - connect(2)

- REQUEST_METHOD                                 : GET
- REQUEST_PATH                                   : /auth/facebook/callback
- REQUEST_URI                                    : /auth/facebook/callback?code=AQDoUnHaO4ShfZUtCw6TVHAd_oOWUQ7Lar-OunhlFHoWhpTmiliY8hWTEb0CmufEMABpUggIlAe15jx8BOxTmVXmHb3JvVlePEfECpkVhf82UWdoHK8jCYN00KM5RYUkbx6M5SHjusb2xWFeHnE92-nfvbpw2KSARqR5njgJqbV_hkJYb42SiuvNXKOTU6hYY_g

------------------------------- Backtrace:

```
/home/finetuning/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
/home/finetuning/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
/home/finetuning/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
/home/finetuning/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
/home/finetuning/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
/home/finetuning/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
/home/finetuning/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
/home/finetuning/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
/home/finetuning/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
faraday (0.7.6) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:61:in `call'
faraday (0.7.6) lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:14:in `call'
faraday (0.7.6) lib/faraday/connection.rb:210:in `run_request'
oauth2 (0.5.2) lib/oauth2/client.rb:88:in `request'
oauth2 (0.5.2) lib/oauth2/client.rb:128:in `get_token'
oauth2 (0.5.2) lib/oauth2/strategy/auth_code.rb:29:in `get_token'
omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:77:in `build_access_token'
omniauth-facebook (1.2.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:63:in `block in build_access_token'
omniauth-facebook (1.2.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:110:in `with_authorization_code'
omniauth-facebook (1.2.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:63:in `build_access_token'
omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:61:in `callback_phase'
```

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem - how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like access tokens needing to be re-requested to me, but that is a not-knowledgable guess.

Theres a bunch of things that stopped the callback from working for me before I got it to work:

- internet connection stalls all together
- no route in config/routes
- bad javascript
- callback url doesn't match on facebook app
- outdated version of oauth.. etc..

Feel free to double check what you have with what I got working and see if it helps:

http://www.ajostrow.me/thoughts/client-side-facebook-authentication-with-rails

Answer (score 1):

was the problem solved in any way? I'm facing it too.

Other discussion:
https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/80

Btw, have you checked open ports?